# Filtering one object with another array's object key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an object with another object inside of an array.

To be more precise, I am trying to compare the keys of the object inside the array, to the keys of my main object. If the values are the same, I want to return the value corresponding to those keys.

Here's an example:

```
var a = {
  "maths":"A++",
  "literature":"C-",
  "sports":"B+",
  "biology":"D",
  "chemistry":"A",
  "english":"A+",
  "physics":"C+"
}


var b = [{
  "maths":"Mathematics",
  "biology":"Biology",
  "physics":"Physics"
}]
```

I wanna check if any of the keys in object `b` are inside object `a` and if they are, I want to return their value into array. For example, I want to return `["A++","D","C+"]`

I've tried using `filter` and `Array.prototype.some` but I couldn't figure out anything. Any advice on how should I achieve this?

Comment: Where does the `C+` come from? It's not present in the input

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, just added it to the object.

Comment: Why not just create nested 2 for in loops and comepare names?

Comment: `Object.keys(b[0]).map(p => a[p])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make an array or Set of all the keys inside `b`, then use `.map` to access each key on the `a` object:

```js
var a = {
  "maths":"A++",
  "literature":"C-",
  "sports":"B+",
  "biology":"D",
  "chemistry":"A",
  "english":"A+",
  "physics":"C+"
}


var b = [{
  "maths":"Mathematics",
  "biology":"Biology",
  "physics":"Physics"
}];
const keys = b.flatMap(Object.keys);
const arr = keys.map(key => a[key]);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a single object in the array `b`, then you can do this:

```js
var a = {
  "maths":"A++",
  "literature":"C-",
  "sports":"B+",
  "biology":"D",
  "chemistry":"A",
  "english":"A+",
  "physics":"C+"
}


var b = [{
  "maths":"Mathematics",
  "biology":"Biology",
  "physics":"Physics"
}]

const valuesInAndB = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc,x) => {
  if (b[0][x]) {
    return acc.concat(a[x]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(valuesInAndB);
```

However, if the objects in `b` will be greater than one then as answered by @certainperformance you could get all the keys in `b` and map through `a` with those keys.

```
const keysInB = b.flatMap(Object.keys);
keysInB.map(key => a[key]);
```

> `flatMap` is not available in some older browsers, please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to handle multiple objects in b.
If so and if you want one array for each object in b then you could do something like:

```js
var a = {
  "maths":"A++",
  "literature":"C-",
  "sports":"B+",
  "biology":"D",
  "chemistry":"A",
  "english":"A+",
  "physics":"C+"
}


var b = [{
  "maths":"Mathematics",
  "biology":"Biology",
  "physics":"Physics"
},{
  "maths":"Mathematics",
  "biology":"Biology",
  "english":"English"
}]

const result = b.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => a[key]));
console.log(result);
```